# RxJS switchMap with the take operator

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a method that returns the following observable.

```
class Service {

  getData() {
     // the select observable will fire on every form change
     return this.store.select('filters').switchMap(filters => {
        return this.http.get('call the api with the filters')
     }).take(1);

  }
}
```

In my component, I call this method on submit.

```
class Component {

   submit() {
     this.service.getData().subscribe(...)
   }
}
```

The problem is that after I call submit once, I see two HTTP calls in the second submit. My question is if the take(1) operator, in this case, is killing both the **inner** and the **outer** observables?

Comment: It is supposed to. Is it possible that, elsewhere in the code, you subscribe to this same observable? Do you create a new subscription when the request is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to the `take()` operator. You're simply making two subscriptions to the same source Observable with two chains.

The `take(1)` operator then just accepts only the first item emitted and send `complete` notification.

Right now you have the following:

```
           +-- switchMap --- take --> subscribe()
-- store --+
           +-- switchMap --- take --> subscribe()
```

So the same value is pushed to two different chains with two different `switchMap`'s.

While you probably want something like this:

```
                         +--> subscribe()
-- store --- switchMap --+
                         +--> subscribe()
```

For example you have this (instead of `do()` you have `switchMap()`):

```
const subject = new Subject();
const obs = subject
    .do(console.log);

obs.subscribe(i => console.log('next:', i));
obs.subscribe(i => console.log('next:', i));

subject.next(1);
```

... which prints the following. Notice that the `do()` operator received two values:

```
1
next: 1
1
next: 1
```

Instead you could use:

```
const obs = subject
    .do(console.log)
    .publish()
    .refCount();
```

or this ...

```
const multicast = new Subject();
const obs = subject
    .do(console.log)
    .subscribe(multicast);

multicast.subscribe(...);
```

or this ...

```
const obs = subject
    .do(console.log)
    .publish();
obs.connect();
```

or whatever depending on what you need.

This goes through just one `do()`:

```
1
next: 1
next: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's still not answering my question. In my example, take(1) is killing both the outer and the inner subscriptions?

Comment: @undefined there's no inner nor outer subscription. When `take(1)` receives a single item i sends `complete` notification which disposes the chain (clears the array of observers). But the operator itself isn't responsible to unsubscribe anything.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code:

```js
readonly propertyA$ = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>('A');
  readonly propertyB$ = new ReplaySubject<string[] | null>(1);

  constructor(ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.propertyB$.next(['B']);
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.propertyB$.next(['B2']);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.propertyA$.next('A2');
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.propertyB$.next(['B3']);
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.propertyB$.next(['B4']);
    }, 6000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.propertyA$.next('A3');
    }, 7000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.propertyB$.next(['B5']);
    }, 8000);


    this.propertyA$.pipe(switchMap(propertyA => {
      return this.propertyB$.pipe(
        take(1), //and without
        map(propertyB => ([propertyA, propertyB] as [string, string[]]))
      )
    })).subscribe(x => console.log('propertyA & propertyB (combineLatestFrom): ', x));
}
```

Without take(1):

```
A, B
A, B2
A2, B2
A2, B3
A2, B4
A3, B4
A3, B5
```

With take(1):

```
A, B
A2, B2
A3, B4
```